# Sendgrid API fetch contacts' detail from a segment with more than 100 contact

Tags: python, sendgrid-api-v3

I try fetching all people's email from a Sendgrid segment.
There should be a way to set up the parameter of limitation on how many contacts, such as param: {'limit':1000}. The default call will return the first 50 people in the segments. How to get the full segment?

```py
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
import json

sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))

segment_id = segment_id
response = sg.client.marketing.segments._(segment_id).get()

data = json.loads(response.body)
contacts = data["contacts_sample"]
```

The result will return a list of every person's email in a segment.

Comment: it is worth including a link `sendgrid` to the docs as this might be the best place for the answer...

Comment: I couldn't find an answer for you in the docs, so it might not be possible. But please remember to migrate to [v2](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/segmenting-contacts-v2/get-list-of-segments) of the API by Dec 31, 2022. For [more info](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/segmentation-v1-api-deprecation) about the deprecation.